# How to gpg encrypt with ssh public key?

Tags: ssh, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I have a public key in a file called `key.pub`, and the contents look like:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB...<snip>...t+f klahnakoski
```

I would like to to use it to encrypt a file with `gpg`.  What is the sequence of shell commands required?

I imagine the sequence looks something like:

- convert key to gpg-friendly format
- invent some credentials to sign key with
- invent a user to facilitate adding key to keyring
- perform the encryption

Thank you!

Comment: Most of us simply create a GPG key.

Answer (score 7):

RSA keys can only be used to encrypt a proportion of their key length. e.g. a 2048 bit RSA key can only be used to encrypt about 245 bytes.

See:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security

So to encrypt / decrypt large amounts of data (files) you would use a symmetric key which was encrypted using a public key, *not* the public key itself.

Also, you wouldn't add a symmetric key to a *public* SSH key, because the the symmetric key is a secret, and the public SSH key *isn't a secret*. The symmetric key should be added to the *private* SSH key.

It goes something like the following:

To convert the file format, install the monkeysphere tool set (Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install monkeysphere
```

Use the pem2openpgp tool to convert the *private* key to gpg format. Pipe to gpg for import.

```
pem2openpgp userid-ssh@example.com < id_rsa | gpg --import

# Check it's there
gpg --list-secret-keys
```

Edit the trust level you have in the key.

```
gpg --edit-key userid-ssh@example.com
gpg> trust
```

Add the trust level you need (ultimate for example)

The key imported is only suitable for creating certificates, not for signing or encryption.

### Encryption

The key is an RSA key and can't be used to encrypt / decrypt large amounts of data. If you want to do that you have to add a symmetric encryption subkey. When you encrypt, GPG will use this subkey rather than the original SSH key.

```
gpg> addkey
Please select what kind of key you want:
   (3) DSA (sign only)
   (4) RSA (sign only)
   (5) Elgamal (encrypt only)
   (6) RSA (encrypt only)
Your selection? 6
```

Now you can encrypt and decrypt using the identity *based on* the SSH key.

```
gpg -vv -r userid-ssh@example.com -e -a unencrypted_file.txt
```

So how useful is this?

Well, it makes more sense to use GPG to generate and manage your SSH keys as authentication subkeys rather than trying to do it the other way round. In fact it can be integrated into SSH instead of ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [ssh-vault](https://ssh-vault.com) could give you some ideas, it follows the same principle of PGP and using the public ssh keys to encrypt the password only.